# How to find out about weird patterns in gam.check of a bam

Tags: residuals, generalized-additive-model, diagnostic

I run a bam with timeseries data and a response variable defined as cbind(positive, negative), family = quasibinomial (because of overdispersion), a number of interactions, and some random effects. When I use gam.check(model, old.style = TRUE)  to get some diagnostic plots I run into some weird patterns.

Especially the one plotting residuals vs. linear predictors is quite striking. Now I am wondering how to find out which datapoints might be the ones causing the pattern in order to understand better what is happening. Plotting the single predictors vs the residuals hasn´t helped me so far. Any clues?!

Thanks for any help.

[image: gam.check plots]